# Capturing Multiple Bracketed Sequences with Regex, Python 3

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm using Python 3 and working with title strings that have a bracketed tag with a pair of names separated by a `+`. Like this: `[John+Alice] A title here.`

I've been using the regex expression `re.search('\[(.+)\]', title)` to get the tag `[John+Alice]`, which is fine, but it's a problem when encountering a title with more than one bracketed tag:

```
[John+Alice] [Hayley + Serene] Another title.
```

That gives me `[John+Alice] [Hayley + Serene]`, when I would prefer `[John+Alice]` and `[Hayley + Serene]`.

How can I modify the regex to give me all bracketed tags that have `+` between `[` and `]`? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make your regex non-greedy, like this:

```
title = '[John+Alice] [Hayley + Serene] Another title.'

for t in re.findall('\[(.+?)\]', title):
    print(t)
```

**Output**

```
John+Alice
Hayley + Serene
```

If you must include the brackets use `finditer`:

```
for t in re.finditer('\[(.+?)\]', title):
    print(t.group())
```

**Output**

```
[John+Alice]
[Hayley + Serene]
```

The non-greedy qualifiers such as `*?, +?, ??` match as little text as possible. You can find more about greedy vs non-greedy in [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#greedy-versus-non-greedy).

**Observation**

In the question you mentioned that you are using `'\[(.+)\]'` to match all bracketed tags that have `+` between `[` and `]`, but actually it does a little more than that. For instance, for the following example:

```
title = '[John+Alice] [Hayley + Serene] [No plus text] Another title.'
re.search('\[(.+)\]', title)
```

returns:

```
[John+Alice] [Hayley + Serene] [No plus text]
```

consequently, my modification (using `finditer`) gives:

```
[John+Alice]
[Hayley + Serene]
[No plus text]
```

Therefore `[No plus text]` is incorrect, to fix that you should use something like:

```
title = '[John+Alice] [Hayley + Serene] [No plus text] Another title.'

for t in re.finditer('\[(.+?\+.+?)?\]', title):
    print(t.group())
```

**Output**

```
[John+Alice]
[Hayley + Serene]
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for this really comprehensive answer! I still have so much more to learn. :)